# Splitting DataFrame and maintaining DataFrame group integrity

Tags: python, group-by

To whom it may concern,

I have a very large dataframe (MasterDataFrame) that contains ~180K groups that I would like to split into 5 smaller DataFrames and process each smaller DataFrame separately. Does anyone know of any way that I could achieve this split into 5 smaller DataFrames without accidentally splitting/jeopardizing the integrity of any of the groups from the MasterDataFrame? In other words, I would like for the 5 smaller DataFrames to not have overlapping groups.

Thanks in advance,

Christos

This is what my dataset looks like:
|======MasterDataset======|
Name    Age  Employer
Tom     12   Walmart
Nick    15   Disney
Chris   18   Walmart
Darren  19   KMart
Nate    43   ESPN
Harry   23   Walmart
Uriel   24   KMart
Matt    23   Disney
.       .     .
.       .     .
.       .     .

I need to be able to split my dataset such that the groups shown in the MasterDataset above are preserved. The smaller groups into which my MasterDataset will be split need to look like this:

|======SubDataset1======|
Name    Age  Employer
Tom     12   Walmart
Chris   18   Walmart
Harry   23   Walmart
Darren  19   KMart
Uriel   24   KMart

|======SubDataset2======|
Name    Age  Employer
Nick    15   Disney
Matt    23   Disney

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean the number of lines with "groups"
For that .iloc should be perfect.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

```
df_1 = df.iloc[0:100000,:]
df_2 = df.iloc[100001:200000,:]
....
```